# How to use objectify locally

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am running locally an application on Google App Engine Java using Objectify but it is writing the entities to the remote server Datastore.

How can I make Objectify use the local Datastore?

Comment: Have you tried following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator). Not so familiar with Objectify but it'd be worth using the Emulator among with Objectify for your use case.

Comment: I just tried to set the datastore variables both with the script, using the google project ID that it creates in my appengine-web.xml and manually, setting the ```DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST``` to my application localhost port. In both case it still try to find a google project ID that do not exist on my Google Cloud Account.

Comment: Can you try running this command [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) before actually running the devserver and the datastore emulator? This will ensure you are using the proper project and credentials. Also, once you've started running the emulator you run "echo $(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-unset)" to make sure all variables are properly set.